# Redirection Doesn't Work

Tags: bash, command-line

I want to put my program's output into a file. I keyed in the following :

```
./prog > log 2>&1
```

But there is nothing in the file **"log"**. I am using the Ubuntu 11.10 and the default shell is bash.

Anybody know the cause of this AND how I can debug this?

Comment: Are you sure the prog produce any output?

Comment: @enzotib: Yes. It does. In fact I am using the gnu scientific lib. It also prints out stuff. When I comment out the line which calls the library function, redirection works fine though. Any idea now?

Answer (score 7):

```
script -c "/path/prog" /path/log.txt
```

Sometimes shell redirecting does not work (specifically - when one shell spawns another shell, I think:). Above is the generic solution that simply grabs all the shell output and places it into the file. In your case this should work as well, since you're expecting output on stdout/stderr.

Answer (score 4):

this worked here, when the `./prog 2>&1 >log.txt` alone, would not work properly:

```
./prog 2>&1 |cat >log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
./prog >> log 2>> log
```

`>> log` to redirect `stdout` to the file

`2>> log` to redirect `stderr` to the file

others use the shorthand `&>>` for both `stdout` and `stderr` but it's not accepted by both my mac and ubuntu :(

extra: `>` overwrites, while `>>` appends